# Pip install tesseract-ocr : failed with exit status 2

Tags: visual-studio, pip, installation, tesseract, cl.exe

I've been trying to install Tesseract-ocr library for a long time. Read many similar problems related with other packages and given solutions and none worked.

I think problem is about the my Microsoft Visual Studio. There is an error given the code below:

> error: command 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\Bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

I uninstalled, reinstalled, updated and tried many things but still not working :(

Thanks already now!

```
C:\Users\af>pip install tesseract-ocr
Collecting tesseract-ocr
  Using cached tesseract-ocr-0.0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from tesseract-ocr)
Building wheels for collected packages: tesseract-ocr
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for tesseract-ocr ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\af\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ggf9qvw1\\tesseract-ocr\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\af\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdnkpad7cpip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
  file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
  running build_ext
  building 'tesseract_ocr' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release
  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\python34\include -Ic:\python34\include /Tptesseract_ocr.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\tesseract_ocr.obj
  tesseract_ocr.cpp
  tesseract_ocr.cpp(463) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'leptonica/allheaders.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for tesseract-ocr
  Running setup.py clean for tesseract-ocr
Failed to build tesseract-ocr
Installing collected packages: tesseract-ocr
  Running setup.py install for tesseract-ocr ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\af\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ggf9qvw1\\tesseract-ocr\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\af\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-tcjuee8m-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
    file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
    running build_ext
    building 'tesseract_ocr' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release
    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\python34\include -Ic:\python34\include /Tptesseract_ocr.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\tesseract_ocr.obj
    tesseract_ocr.cpp
    tesseract_ocr.cpp(463) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'leptonica/allheaders.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\af\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ggf9qvw1\\tesseract-ocr\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\af\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-tcjuee8m-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\af\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ggf9qvw1\tesseract-ocr\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using pytesseract, worked for me on python 3.6: pip install pytesseract

If you encounter problems installing it directly by running the above command, try this link :
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Use the "find" tool to find pytesseract and in the directory where its downloaded, hold shift and right click, youll get an option to open a command window there and run:

pip install "filename"

You could also try downloading tesseract-ocr from the link above and perform the installation offline like i just explained.
Never quite figured out why, but some installations that failed worked when dowloaded. Hope that helps.

Comment: No such wheel at the web link you posted and installing pytesseract doesn't resolve the error either.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this issue is on the [Compiling Page](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling) of tesseract-ocr

> sudo apt-get install libleptonica-dev

I can tell you that this fixed the issue on a Raspberry Pi (Jessie and Stretch) and Debian (8 and 9)