# Install tesseract-ocr in Windows10

Tags: python, windows-10, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm tring to install tesseract-ocr but I always get this error

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install tesseract-ocr
Collecting tesseract-ocr
  Using cached tesseract-ocr-0.0.1.tar.gz (33 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cython in d:\python310\lib\site-packages (from tesseract-ocr) (0.29.32)
Building wheels for collected packages: tesseract-ocr
  Building wheel for tesseract-ocr (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
      file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
      running build_ext
      building 'tesseract_ocr' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -ID:\Python310\include -ID:\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um /EHsc /Tptesseract_ocr.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\tesseract_ocr.obj
      tesseract_ocr.cpp
      tesseract_ocr.cpp(779): fatal error C1083: ????????: "leptonica/allheaders.h": No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tesseract-ocr
```

Is something wrong with leptonica?
But I've already installed leptonica, pytesseract and tesseract.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a version newer than 0.0.1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip install tesseract-ocr : failed with exit status 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595255/pip-install-tesseract-ocr-failed-with-exit-status-2)